# Getting information from background thread onto the main thread for Swift

Tags: multithreading, swift, parsing, background-process

I seem to be having some trouble getting information from my global queue into my main queue.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(Int(QOS_CLASS_USER_INTERACTIVE.value), 0)) {
        let query = PFQuery(className: "VenueData")
        query.whereKey("name", equalTo: "Sedona")
        var object = query.findObjects()
        if let myObject = object as? [PFObject] {
            for x in myObject {
                var hotelLabel: String? = x.objectForKey("name") as? String
                println(hotelLabel)
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    self.new = hotelLabel!
                    self.hotelarray.append(self.new)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Even though I am able to change the UI through the dispatch_get_main_queue, I seem to be having trouble updating other stuff (e.g. Array) and if I were to println(hotelarray) outside of the block, only an empty array would show up.

I understand this happens because the mainthread loads significantly faster than the time it takes for the background thread to load its data. What is puzzles me is that it seems as if the hotel array will not get updated regardless of what happens inside the dispatch_get_main_queue whereas UI related stuff such as UILabels updates accordingly. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "I seem to be having trouble updating other stuff (e.g. Array)". What "trouble?" What "Array?" What do you expect will happen? What actually does happen? How do you know that is what happens?

Comment: What I meant is when I wrote self.hotelarray.append(self.new), I was expecting the hotel array to be updated after the background thread finishes loading the data. So I would write println(hotelarray) outside the closure and would only receive nil. Whereas if I were to do the same to a UILabel, the label would change accordingly after the background thread loads it data.

Comment: What you're describing does not make sense. If `hotelarray` is of type `[String]`, which it appears to be, there is no case where it can print the string "nil", unless perhaps "name" itself is "nil". You need to be precise (in your question; comments are too limiting) about how you are *actually* testing this, and what exactly it prints (including brackets, quotes, commas, etc.)

Comment: Not sure what you mean about printing outside of the block. You have to access the array after you set the value, that is inside the block (or in a method called from inside the block).

Comment: @RobNapier I honestly thought nil and and an empty array were the same thing but you're right. Sorry about my syntax. The print was not actually nil but just empty. And I'll keep in mind the next time I ask questions to be more thorough.

Comment: This is a very valid question and does provides good details if you analyse correctly. ( its mainly about handling arrays within and outside closures) . The appraoch to answer the question should have been less aggressive. Humbleness and simplicity is a quality of greatness